# Why does this h3/a element have extra space on the bottom?

Tags: html, css, text, sass

I am coding a website and I have a header element that contains an anchor with some text. However, the text is, for some reason, aligned to the top of the h3/a element and I cannot get it to vertically align or get the h3 to fit the text.

The h3 element SASS is:

```
h3
  font-family: "Bebas Neue Regular", sans-serif
  font-size: 60px
  font-weight: normal
  letter-spacing: 3px
  color: white
```

Additionally, here is a picture of the problem:
[image: Header Element Error]

There are a couple of additional styles from normalize.css and the user agent as well:

```
h3 {
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.17em; //overridden
  -webkit-margin-before: 1em;
  -webkit-margin-after: 1em;
  -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
  -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
  font-weight: bold; //overridden
}

//the h3 inherits this
html { 
  line-height: 1.15;
}
```

In regards to the line-height, I have tried setting it to 1 and the advised 0.8em, but these values make no difference when I add them to the styles.

This is a picture of what happened when I tried to artificially change the line-height by putting `line-height: 0.8em` on the h3 element.

[image: Header with changed line-height]

Comment: You are not providing a reproducible example, at least add the html structure to make it snippetable when asking html and css related question.

Comment: If the question really is *why*, then just consider a document [without stylesheets](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_basic_document). Of course you want space under your headings! It's been so for a very long time and it only makes sense. User-agent is your browser, and a normalize-style only aims to normalize the differences between browsers.  So again, no surprises here really. Setting a `margin:0;` is not that difficult either.

Comment: I've come here with the same problem - none of the answers are relevant to this question. 
@ippi, setting margin to zero does not work here. The problem is specific to the font itself because the characters have extra space beneath them. The only solution is to choose a different font or somehow edit the glyphs and make your own version.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that you can't with CSS - there is something odd about this font that means it has extra space below the characters built into it. You can see this on the Google Fonts page: https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Bebas+Neue?preview.text=Tom%20D%20Chambers&preview.text_type=custom#about.

[image]

The solution is to use a different font that doesn't have this (unusual) issue.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it may have an extra line-height attribute being set. Could you also add a full list of the computed styles from chromes developer tools?

Answer (score 0):

The space is there for [character descenders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descender).  You can adjust the `line-height` property to remove it if desired by shrinking the line height below it's natural value.  For example:

```
line-height: 0.8em;
```

Comment: I have tried this (I put the value directly on the h3 element, but it did not make ant difference). The h3 box does get smaller, but the text inside just passes right through.

Answer (score -1):

I have fixed this before by changing the `display` property to `block`.

Answer (score -2):

Its get vary font by font 
you can fix this issue by given `line-height` to your properties.